# php directory listing files in numerical order

Tags: php, function

How would I change this function so that it listed the files in order as currently they are sorted randomly. I have already changed it so it excludes the Index.php file. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function DirDisply() {
$TrackDir=opendir(".");

while ($file = readdir($TrackDir)) {
$info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
if ($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php"){ }
else {
print "<p><a class=btn href=$file target=content>Item Number $file_name</a></p>";

}
}
closedir($TrackDir);
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using glob() and sort the array the way you want.

Comment: I did not know that function exists! That's pretty cool. For reference: http://php.net/glob

Answer (score 1):

If you want some **natural** ordering you can combine scandir and natsort.

```
    $images = array_diff(scandir($the_path), array('..', '.'));
    natsort($images);
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        // TODO
    }
```

natsort **natural** ordering from [php.net](http://php.net/natsort) :

> This function implements a sort algorithm that orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would

It's an alphabetical order but it takes care of index number in similar filenames :

```
file-2.jpg
file-1.jpg
file-10.jpg
```

will be ordered

```
file-1.jpg
file-2.jpg
file-10.jpg
```

scandir, on the other hand, will only order in alphabetical order like :

```
file-1.jpg
file-10.jpg
file-2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to continue to use `readdir()` you'd have to set a new array inside your while loop, and then manage the array sorting it in whatever order you want.

Personally I'd switch to `scandir()` as it has a sorting option built in and already sorts alphabetically in ascending order into an array (less code, easier to maintain etc):
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Either way you would have to have the foreach on the array, so `scandir()` is the better approach as it means no while loop as well.

`scandir()` returns an array, which can (arguably) be easy to manage than looping through the folder with `readdir()` as you can check a final outcome in one go. IE check the array is an array, has keys, values, loop it, check each one on loop, etc.

Then rather than `while` as you currently have, just use `scandir()` and `foreach` the array which `scandir()` returns.

Example as requested (although it's just from php.net, it is a good basic example):

```
$dir    = 'yourdir';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);  //Reverse order

print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);
```

The 1 in `$files2` reverses the order. The default sorting order is ascending (0 but no need to specify this) and 1 for descending.
Of course you'd loop the array (`$files1`) using your code:
`print "<p><a class=btn href=$file target=content>Item Number $file_name</a></p>";`
Where the value of the array you loop will be your filename.

You should have a read at the php net for all these functions whenever you use one. If you looked up your original function `readdir()` on php.net there is (nearly) always links to similar functions, and you would have found `scandir()` ;)

SIDE NOTE:
Also. you check if something = something and if true do nothing, else do something. This is not the right approach for this scenario.
You should just do something if it = something, such as:

```
if ($file != "." || $file != ".." 
    || $file != "index.php")
  { 
    print "<p><a class=btn 
           href=$file target=content>Item Number $file_name</a></p>";
  }
```

You could even have an else report an error or "no files" or whatever.

Comment: Thankyou for this I will make your sidenote changes. would yo be able to make an example for the scandir() as im very new to PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Hope that helps :)